# Best Practices for Error Codes in Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, error-handling

I configured an exception for a specific error and I receive something like this:

```
<ef_Anula_DocumentoResponse>
   <error>Null field</error>
</ef_Anula_DocumentoResponse>
```

Now, I want to display an error code for each exception. How is the best way to achieve this?:
(These are just examples)

```
<error>1, Null field</error>
<error><1>Null field</1></error>
<error>1;Null field</error>
```

There is a specific convention for this type of situation?

My problem is when I make  `<error><1>Null field</1></error>`, '<1' and '1>' are replaced by <1 and 1> and decode these to appear friendly in SOAP UI is considered Bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized by some links that the spected behaviour is:

```
   <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <S:Body>
          <ns2:ef_Anula_DocumentoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.jaxws.sgd.ws.airc/">
             <error_code>100</error_code>
             <error>Null field</error>         
          </ns2:ef_Anula_DocumentoResponse>
       </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

Hope that help in Future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try maybe the below xml output if you want to return multiple errors?

```
<errors>
    <error>
        <code>1</code>
        <desc>Null field</desc>
    </error>
    <error>
        <code>2</code>
        <desc>Null field</desc>
    </error>
</errors>
```

Comment: It´s not what I want, My 3 examples were just a behaviour for one method, and different answers for one response. But I will keep your structure.